# ErrorOccurred the Ad in windows phone 8.1 in AdControl

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, ads

I have a test Adunit

```
 <UI:AdControl AdUnitId="Image480_80"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Width="480"
            Height="80"
            ApplicationId="test_client"
            Loaded="AdUnit_Loaded"
            Tapped="AdUnit_Tapped"
            AdRefreshed="AdControl_AdRefreshed"
            ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred"  />
```

I get the following error :

> Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Common.AdException: HTTP error status
>   code: NotFound (404) --->  System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   ServerSideErrorr returned an error: NotFound. 
>   MS.Internal.Modern.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   MS.Internal.Modern.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Common.HttpRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Common.WebRequestWrapper.WebRespCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- NetworkConnectionFailure

How to go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Is the device that you are getting this error on have an internet connection when the error is thrown?

Comment: You must have to add different AdUnitId which is the Id of the Ad